# Toggle 4 different windows with 4 unique shortcuts

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I always have four different application windows open in the same position. I want to assign shortcuts to each one that will allow me to focus that window regardless of the previously focused window. I am thinking of using `Super + [window #]` to toggle the windows. The desired setup is below.

```
-----------------------------    -----------------------------
|                           |    |                           |
|                           |    |                           |
|                           |    |                           |
|          Window 1         |    |          Window 2         |
|                           |    |                           |
| Focus by pressing Super+1 |    | Focus by pressing Super+2 |
|                           |    |                           |
|                           |    |                           |
|                           |    |                           |
-----------------------------    -----------------------------

-----------------------------    -----------------------------
|                           |    |                           |
|                           |    |                           |
|                           |    |                           |
|          Window 3         |    |          Window 4         |
|                           |    |                           |
| Focus by pressing Super+3 |    | Focus by pressing Super+4 |
|                           |    |                           |
|                           |    |                           |
|                           |    |                           |
-----------------------------    -----------------------------
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I'm using Ubuntu 16. The windows are really spread across 3 different screens but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: Are they four different applications? If yes, you can pin (lock) them to the Unity launcher in the desired positions.

Comment: No two of them are terminator windows, one is a chrome browser, and the fourth is a chrome devtools window. But maybe I could still use pins on the launcher? I'll look into it

Comment: You might be able to make a custom .desktop file for each of the terminator windows, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding the applications as favorites in the Ubuntu/Gnome Dock and toggling with `Super-1`, `Super-2`, etc in Ubuntu 16. Then switched to putting the applications in different workspaces in Ubuntu 18 as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188087/creating-distinct-duplicates-of-applications-in-unity)