# Creating distinct duplicates of applications in Gnome3

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, terminator

Previously on Ubuntu 16 I had 3 duplicates of Terminator in `/usr/share/applications/` (`t3.desktop`, `t4.desktop`, and `t5.desktop`) so that I could use each for a different use case - vim for coding, vim for note-taking, other terminal stuff - and access them quickly by adding them as different favorites in the Unity Dock and pressing `Super-3`, `Super-4`, and `Super-5`.

Trying to do this in Ubuntu 18, all of the duplicates open at the same time are considered the same application and appear as different windows of the same application in the Dock. Therefore I can't set them as different favorites in the Dock and access them with the `Super-*` shortcuts.

Any ideas of how to get them to show up as different applications to Unity/the Dock?

Update: Add desktop file contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=t3
Comment=Multiple terminals in one window
TryExec=terminator
Exec=terminator
Icon=terminator
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;System;
StartupNotify=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=terminator
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;
Keywords=terminal;shell;prompt;command;commandline;
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=terminator
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

-

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=t4
Comment=Multiple terminals in one window
TryExec=terminator
Exec=terminator
Icon=terminator
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;System;
StartupNotify=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=terminator
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;
Keywords=terminal;shell;prompt;command;commandline;
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=terminator
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Comment: please paste the contents of .desktop files

Comment: @cmak.fr - added contents of .desktop files

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just putting the different windows of Terminator in workspaces 3, 4, and 5 and toggling between the workspaces as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/427448/725311), making the toggling between them fast as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1083797/725311).