# Creating a duplicate Terminator application in /usr/bin/

Tags: python, terminator

I'm trying to copy my `/usr/bin/terminator` as downloaded on Ubuntu 18 with `apt-get install terminator`. I do `sudo cp /usr/bin/terminator /usr/bin/terminator2`. When I run `terminator2` though, I get a Python exception thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/t5", line 47, in <module>
    import terminatorlib.optionparse
ImportError: No module named terminatorlib.optionparse
```

How is the `terminatorlib` Python module imported/seen by the original `/usr/bin/terminator`?

For the record, I'm trying to make duplicates of the app for easy Dock access as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188087/creating-distinct-duplicates-of-applications-in-unity).

Comment: Is terminator a binary? Try to do less /usr/bin/terminator

Comment: @jugmac00 no it's a Python script. I can open up the script and edit it fine, so I'm just looking how to make the Python code work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment above that `terminator` is a Python script, before running the script, you can set a break point via `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`.

Start `terminator` and you will be in an interactive session.

You can then enter `import terminatorlib` and then `terminatorlib.__file__` - this shows you where the package / module is located.

If you prefer a simple solution, just visit this site:
https://superuser.com/questions/625445/create-multiple-instance-of-terminator